# MS CRON expression for Azure Function (22:30 - 12:00)

Tags: azure, function, triggers, scheduling, portal

I need a CRON expression, compatible with Azure Functions V2, to express such interval:

- every 30 minutes from 22:30 to 00:00 (including 22:30 and 00:00)

Comment: Please provide more information like what you have tried or error screenshots if you are getting any.

Answer (score 1):

@Cinosarge could you please try this

```
 30,0 22-23,0 * * *
```

this will run at 10:30 PM, 11:00 PM, 11:30 PM, and 12:00 AM (midnight) every day.